# Can I use mono sound on a set of headphones instead of stereo?

Tags: audio, headphones

I have a friend that is deaf on one ear and she would like to get all the sound through one ear bud. Is it possible to get mono sound instead of the default stereo sound through the headphones?

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with a setting in Android to mix both channels but perhaps [this stereo to mono adapter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=3.5mm%20stereo%20to%20mono&hl=en&biw=1018&bih=789&prmd=ivns&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=138632743896099250&sa=X&ei=b4ZATpS6M-Tw0gHX1JCdBw&ved=0CH4Q8wIwAA) could help.

Comment: That's mono to stereo...

Comment: @BloodPhilia Take a look at the photo of that plug (I don't have enough points to post the image in the body of the answer). You plug it into your phone's stereo jack. Then you plug your mono ear bud into it. That's stereo to mono. I know this works because I have been using it myself (for an [under-the-pillow speaker](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103574)).

Comment: You might want to look for a TRRS (tip ring ring sleeve) to mono converter, some android phones have an FM radio lead soldered into the headset jack, and can have weird reactions to just a TRS ("stereo") or TS ("mono") plug